# Data type vs. Constraint for saving numbers in Datawarehouse

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to save two digit numbers. The time to store the data does not matter. Reading is critical. There are a lot of rows.

I could do this in different ways:

- a column of the type tinyint
- a column of the type tinyint with a constraint "< 100"
- a column of the type numeric(2,0)
- a column of the type char(2)
- a column of the type char(2) with a constraint "[0-9][0-9]"
- any other??

Which is the most performant solution? (Memory, CPU)

Does the answer depend on an index/type of index on the column?
Does the answer depend on the number of rows stored in that column?

Comment: When reading is critical it mostly depends on which form of the data in question is preferable for the reader. Anyway a check constraint doesn't affect reading and should be added to the column.

Comment: CCI uses compression so yes, index type matter. See this related question on Database Administrators. [Do BIT columns offer any performance advantages for CCIs?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183562/do-bit-columns-offer-any-performance-advantages-for-ccis)

Comment: Sorry, there is only ncci as I am on SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as storage is concerned, tinyint uses 1 byte per entry, numeric(2,0) uses 5 bytes per entry and char(2) uses 2 bytes. Constrains have no impact on storage.

As far as CPU/speed is concerned, it depends pretty much of what you do with the result -- like join, or filter, or sort -- and the conversions the sql-server optimizer thinks it has to do.

However, experiment on 10 millions records with a java JDBC, shows that reading char(2) takes 1.5 more time than reading tinyint, and reading numeric(2,0) takes twice the time of reading tinyint.

Constraints have an clear impact on writing, but low impact on reading, except in very special cases like the one mentioned by @DanGuzman [WHERE col=100] or @Christian4143 [Hudge Volume].

Comment: Are you sure about constraints having no impact on reading? I compared a count distinct on a 900 millions record table (>20GB ) and did see (although small) differences. I will try to reproduce the results. Shouldn't there be an impact of the constraints on the query plan/optimizer?

Comment: @Christian4143, check constraints can be used by the optimizer to optimize queries if they are trusted. I can't speak to your specific test but with check constraint `(col1 < 100)` and predicate  `WHERE col1 = 100`, I'd expect the query to be a complete no-op. You'll generally get best performance simply by using the data type most appropriate for the domain of data stored. `tinyint` with a check constraint would be best for positive integers under 100.

Comment: Ok, I correct: "Constraints have no impact on reading" into "Constraints have low impact on reading, unless in very special cases [WHERE col >100]".

Answer (score 2):

Use "a column of the type tinyint with a constraint "< 100". Tinyint uses 1 byte storage in sql. Even indexes created on smaller storage columns are faster since fewer rows fit on same sql page.

[Index design guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095(v=sql.110).aspx)

For better performance, your clustered index should be optimal, and better with a narrow index. Yes, size of data also matters but good index and choosing less number of columns in sql with orderly use of columns in WHERE clause can overcome much of that.

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/index-selection-and-the-query-optimizer